# best way to compress uploaded photos and videos with python and django to reduce storage

Tags: python, django, compression, media

Hoping I can get some suggestions here, thanks for the help.

I am building a django python based web app where users will be able to upload photos and videos that they would take with their mobile phone. At this stage I would be limiting each user to 10 photos or videos, but we have high user volumes so the main concern here is storage space consumption.

What are some recommended compression packages that could be used to store the photos and videos?

Thanks for any recommendations.

I had a look at tinypng which would be fine for images but I dont think it processes videos. I also expect that the file formats for the images and videos could be a range of formats, there is no specific format that I need to store the media files as.

Comment: if it's jpeg or any already compressed format, you're wasting our time. If you want to compress PNG or other not compressed format, you just need to transform the image to the other format with the proper library

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The user would be taking the photo or video with their mobile phone as mentioned above, so I assume the default would be something like heif for images and hevc for video?